# How can I use remote server with Macvim on the command line?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

```
mvim --servername master
```

works, but loads the gui

```
mvim -v --servername master
```

doesnt

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

```
:h macvim-clientserver
```

There is a note at the bottom stating it doesn't work.

Comment: Namely, "The current implementation assumes that the NSConnections use mach ports for interprocess communication.  This means that you can only use Vim's client/server feature on a local machine (and not across a network)." That's a pity; hopefully in the future it will use TCP sockets too.